# Set curser in a TextFormField inside a Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container that has a text field (an instance of a `TextFormField`) and a border (optional). I need to set focus on the text field inside the container when I click on anywhere on the container. So, I added a `FocusNode` instance to my text field.

Now I need to color the border of my container. The logic is, if the container is tapped, it should be colored and the curser should be blinking in the text field. Otherwise, there should be no border and no curser in the text field.

However, I need to click twice to set the cursor inside the text field. If I remove the border permanently, I can set the curser by a single click. I'm struggling to find out what I am doing wrong here.

The code is as below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextInputCard extends StatefulWidget {
  TextInputCard({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextInputCardState createState() => _TextInputCardState();
}

class _TextInputCardState extends State<TextInputCard> {
  FocusNode _inputFocusNode = FocusNode();

  Color boarderColor;

  void _onFocusChange() {
    setState(() {
      if (_inputFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        boarderColor = Colors.black;
      } else {
        boarderColor = null;
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _buildInput() {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
        child: TextFormField(
          focusNode: _inputFocusNode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
            labelText: "Test Label",
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _inputFocusNode.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _inputFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _inputFocusNode.requestFocus(),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: boarderColor != null
              ? BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: boarderColor,
                    width: 2.0,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                )
              : null,
          child: Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildInput(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why it happens but the issue is because the border is optional. When I keep the border always (making it transparent when I don't need it), it works like a charm.

So I changed `_onFocusChange` method like below,

```
  void _onFocusChange() {
    setState(() {
      if (_inputFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        boarderColor = Colors.black;
      } else {
        boarderColor = Colors.transparent;
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps :-)